# Clarification in a theorem statement regarding intersection of Complex Algebraic Curves in $P_2$

Tags: algebraic-curves, projective-geometry

I have a theorem in the book  **Complex Algebraic Curves- Frances Kirwan** :

*If two projective curves $C$ and $D$ of degrees $n$ and $m$ respectively in $P_2$ intersect at exactly $n^2$ points and if $nm$ points if these lie on an irreducible curve $E$ of degree $m < n$ then the remaining $n(n-m)$ points of intersection lie on a curve of degree at most $n-m$.

My question is do we count the multiplicity of intersection while counting the $n^2$ points?

For instance if we have a point of intersection of multiplicity $2$, do we count the point once or twice?

Comment: Yes: these points are counted with multiplicities.

Comment: @Crostul thanks!!